# Media query not showing up in chrome inspection tool, only with this specific code. What is causing this?

Tags: html, css

But the problem is only with this specific code. There's a lot of other codes that I use as example and Media Query does show up.

But the problem is only with this specific code. There's a lot of other codes that I use as example and Media Query does show up.

How to make it show up so I can edit it from there?

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 24px 40px 15px 20px;
}

#header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 410px) {
  #nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">


  <nav id="nav-bar">

    <div class="nav-link">Pricing</div>
    <div class="nav-link">How It Works</div>
    <div class="nav-link">Features</div>

  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: In what way does this *not* work?

Comment: It works, but, it doesn't show up in chrome inspection tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your media querie syntax to:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 410px) {
      // Code goes here
 }
```

Comment: You mean like that?

@media screen and (max-width: 410px) {
        #nav-bar {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 30px; 
            padding: 0 50px;
        }
 }

It works as before , but, still not showing up in chrome inspection tool

Comment: Yes, but strage... i´ll let you know when i found a solution